# Intent is not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have the below code :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<RowItem> rowItems;

    private static Integer[] images = { R.drawable.red, R.drawable.spidy,
            R.drawable.prisoners, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.spidy };

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myList);
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        String[] titles = { "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie4", "Movie5" };
        String[] descriptions = { "First Movie", "Second movie", "Third Movie",
                "Fourth Movie", "Fifth Movie" };
        // Populate the List
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        // Set the adapter on the ListView
        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, rowItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), News.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);

                // startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }    
}
```

I have written `Toast` ans `startIntent` on item click, but it is not working. Neither toast is display nor new activity is starting. I have also tried `onItemSelection` method but it is not working. How can i used this in this `Fragment` class?

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card_greenborder"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Dog Tag"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dhoom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Create an NFC Pet Tag"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnregister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to send data from one fragment to another then use Bundle...You can't send data by using intent with fragments.

Comment: no i dont want to send data. i just want to open new activity.

Comment: do you want to open activity from fragment ?

Comment: yes i want to open activity from this fragment

Comment: don't use onItemSelected Listener.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @RohitGoswami i have used `setOnItemClickListener` . check my code.

Comment: @Muthu no i am not geting any errors.

Comment: but why are you using onItemSelected...so remove and test

Comment: @RohitGoswami i have remoed it and also tried but still it is not working

Comment: show me this xml file list_row

Comment: Did you debug the code and check it is come to onclick listener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't need to be implement `OnItemSelectedListener` for `ListView`. Just remove it.

Second make

```
android:focusable = "false"
android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"
```

for your `UI`s in custom inflated views in listview

Comment: In `list_row.xml` file for all Uis

Comment: I have told you to make for all UIs not for your parent layout @deepak

Comment: Means have to put this lines in all xml file?

Comment: Not in all xml. but for TextView , ImageView and Button in list_row.xml file

Comment: oh...sorry. its done. working. Thank you. :-) you always rock. :-)

Comment: Wel come. Glad to help you!